# CSS selectors assistance with using > *

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to use the following selectors in my tailwinds CSS styling

```
.class > * {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Where I assign a class- I can use the > * selectors to assign the following width.

I have researched on the Tailwinds CSS, but have been unable to determine how to apply this to a div enclosing some children.

One idea would be to mix vanilla CSS with Tailwinds CSS—or to use some Tailwinds CSS option that I have been unable to locate.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what effect you want to achieve? Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to access children in Tailwindcss is to class `[&>]` to the parent div. For example, let's say you have 5 child divs. If you want to reach all of the children, it is sufficient to give the `[&>*]` class. I have created a demo for you to understand better.

[Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/rGQktdY4F1)

Comment: You'll then have to complete the selector with your desired classes, in your specific case, use ```[&>*]:w-1/3```.

Comment: Yes, I showed it in demo. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[&>*]:` works fine but tailwind also offers a simpler selector to achieve the same goal. Simply prepend your tailwind classes with `*:` and the styling will be applied to all the direct children of your element.

You can find and example on Tailwind documentation, [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-direct-children).